# Draw user's attention to a UITextView in IOS

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

When a certain value is selected from an actionsheet (I am using [AcitonSheetPicker 3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)), I programmatically set a label and uitextview's hidden to false (so I show the item). By default it's not there.

I'd like to draw the user's attention to the newly added label and textview. Of course it would still be a required field, but I thought it might be a better user experience to briefly point out that it was added.

Since the action sheet is going to occupy the screen until the user makes a selection from the picker, the thing is they won't actually see the field as it becomes visible, so I thought it would be best to animate it in some way.

Are there any options at my disposal to briefly flash a textview, potentially in a certain color or style that might appealing but consistent with Apple design? I am using Swift and Xcode 6 and am targeting ios7 and 8 devices.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an animation block and iterate a couple of flashes. Then play the animation over a period of 1 or 0.5 seconds, whatever fits best.

Animation block:

```
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:i*0.1 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                   if (i ==0 || i == 2){
                     //set to first colour 
                     self.textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                   }else if(i==4){
                     //reset to white colour or default textfield colour
                     self.textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                   }else{
                     //set to second colour 
                     self.textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
                }];
            }
        }completion:nil];
```

Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html